# Ansible module for aws extras analgous to the yum_repository

Tags: ansible, amazon-linux-2

AWS' Linux 2 has a facility "[Amazon Linux Extras](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras)" which provides additional repos for assorted things (nginx, php, mariadb, etc. etc.).

I'm surprised that I can't find an Ansible module(s) for this feature.  I found an repo in github for this, but it's empty.

I can work around this by hand crafting yum_repository module tasks.  That demands reverse engineering what AWS's CLI command (aka amazon-linux-extras install ...) is doing.  Or I could run that command directly, but that of course will trigger a change every time I run the playbook.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could write an Ansible module to support the amazon linux extras package manager. With a little work you might be able to get that accepted into Ansible.

Answer (score 13):

A reasonable work around, until a module shows up for amazon-linux-extras.

```
- command: amazon-linux-extras install nginx1.12=latest -y
  args:
    creates: /sbin/nginx
```

The `creates` arg. is the hack to make commands the task reasonably idempotent.

Comment: While good for a one-off, this is an unsatisfactory way to manage dependencies across what is currently 51 different "extras" topics (requiring filesystem knowledge for each).  Among other things, changing the expected version in the command would never update the package!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your tasks:

```
- name: Enable amazon-linux-extras packages
  shell: amazon-linux-extras enable postgresql14
```

Then you can use yum to manage the package.

Comment: Don't forget to add the 
```args:
    creates: ....```

Comment: @IvailoBardarov What should args:create: look like for this task?

Comment: I don't have `args: creates: ...` and my code works perfectly without it.

Comment: with args creates syntax we specify what files/folders/etc are created with this task. that way if they are found the operation will be marked as green.
It is important to have only green tasks on re-run. 
That we make the tasks idempotent
With this you gain speed and it's clear when action is really required